# xclip-mode returns "Unknown upattern" and does not work

Tags: linux, clipboard

The command `M-x xclip-mode` returns the following info in `*Messages*`:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (error "Unknown upattern `(quote pbpaste)'") [2 times]
Xclip mode enabled
```

I cannot yank text from X11 clipboard. If I add `(xclip-mode t)` to my `.emacs` file, I get the same message and the killed text cannot be yanked using `C-y`.

Here is the related content in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t) ;; Save clipboard strings into kill ring before replacing them
;; (setq x-select-enable-primary t) ;; Emacs commands C-w and C-y to use the primary selection.
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t) ;; Emacs commands C-w and C-y to use the clipboard selection.
(setq select-enable-clipboard t)
(xclip-mode t) ;; the usual kill/yank commands will use the GUI selections according to select-enable-clipboard/primary.
```

and version info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:    9.6
Codename:   stretch
$ emacs -version
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
$ xclip -version
xclip version 0.12
xclip-1.5$ ls
xclip-autoloads.el  xclip.el  xclip-pkg.el  xclip-pkg.elc
```

Comment: I don't know why you have this problem. You may want to try updating your Emacs version which is quite outdated. You may also want to try GPastel (https://gitlab.petton.fr/DamienCassou/gpastel) instead of xclip (I'm the author of GPastel).

Comment: @DamienCassou Thanks! I upgraded to emacs25 and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in xclip-1.5 which made it signal an error on Emacs<25.
I just pushed a new version 1.6 which should fix this problem.

Comment: Yep! I upgraded to emacs25 using testing repository and the problem solved.